Why is .* not matching full string in Python regex?
Running this code:
my_string = 'START\r\nwords\t" Quoted Words"\r\nmore12345\t$$symbols\r\n END'
pattern = '(.*)'
matches = re.match(pattern, my_string)
matches.groups(0)

I expect the output:
('START\r\nwords\t" Quoted Words"\r\nmore12345\t$$symbols\r\n END',)

but I get:
('START\r',)

How can I match the entire string?

You could just delete your question and your answer and get all your points back.

I didn't downvote, but your question shows no research effort at all. Maybe you actually put a lot of time and energy into finding the answer on your own, but it's not reflected in your post.

100% - to be clear I don't care too much about the points. Just as a frequent user of this site, I know that people have trouble formulating the "original" question that StackOverflow deems as legitimate. New users may not realize that it is the newline that causes the issue, and it's nice to have greater coverage of the question space.

You need to use the re.DOTALL flag to change the behavior of the . character, which by default only matches characters except for \n.
That would make the code become:
my_string = 'START\r\nwords\t" Quoted Words"\r\nmore12345\t$$symbols\r\n END'
pattern = '(.*)'
matches = re.match(pattern, my_string, flags=re.DOTALL)
matches.groups(0)

and the output would be, as expected:
('START\r\nwords\t" Quoted Words"\r\nmore12345\t$$symbols\r\n END',)

